# Добавление параметра в файле ini в нужное место... Python3 + Tkinter

Tags: python, файлы, tkinter, txt

Есть файл `Config.ini` с содержимым:

```
[Station]
bvUseRes=1

[Def]
tvnLoadInMemory=1.0

[Comment]
fLengthMax=250
```

---

Есть такой код, добавляющий строку:

```
def add():
    f = open('Config.ini', 'a')
    f.write('Param=1')
    f.close()

window = Tk()
window.title("Config Manager")
window.geometry('700x500')
Button(window, text='Записать', command=add).grid(column=0, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Он добавляет `Param=1` в конец содержимого.
Как можно доработать код, чтобы реализовать добавление в нужный раздел([Station] или [Def] или [Comment]), не удаляя и не заменяя другие уже присутствующие параметры?

Comment: попробуйте https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import configparser


def save_config():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config['Station'] = {'bvUseRes': '3'}
    config['Def'] = {'tvnLoadInMemory': '3.0'}
    config['Station']['User'] = 'hg'
    config['Comment'] = {'fLengthMax': '450'}
    with open(r'F:\py\Skyrim\example.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)

window = Tk()
window.title("Config Manager")
window.geometry('700x500')
Button(window, text='Записать', command=save_config).grid(column=0, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Изменения в Config.ini:

```
[Station]
bvUseRes=3
user = hg

[Def]
tvnLoadInMemory=3.0

[Comment]
fLengthMax=450
```

Так же в код можно добавить например переключатели:

```
w1 = Scale(window, from_=0, to=42)
w1.grid(column=0, row=6)
w1.set(21)
w2 = Scale(window, from_=0, to=200, length=600, tickinterval=10, orient=HORIZONTAL)
w2.set(101)
w2.grid(column=0, row=7)
```

(беру пример из своего кода)

И спариваем в общей массе. Получаем переменные со слайдера "`w1.get()/w2.get()`" и подключаем в нужное место

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import configparser


def save_config():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config['Station'] = {'bvUseRes': w1.get()}
    config['Def'] = {'tvnLoadInMemory': '3.0'}
    config['Station']['User'] = 'hg'
    config['Comment'] = {'fLengthMax': w2.get()}
    with open(r'F:\py\Skyrim\example.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)

window = Tk()
window.title("Config Manager")
window.geometry('700x500')
w1 = Scale(window, from_=0, to=42)
w1.grid(column=0, row=6)
w1.set(21)
w2 = Scale(window, from_=0, to=200, length=600, tickinterval=10, orient=HORIZONTAL)
w2.set(101)
w2.grid(column=0, row=7)
Button(window, text='Записать', command=save_config).grid(column=0, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```